# How to get user id(UID) from firebase realtime database without login

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

How to get user id ( UID) from firebase realtime database without login.

```
String currentuser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

Because this code works when any firebase user is loged in. For example if an user is loged in and he wants to get the UID of another user then how can he get the UID of that user.

[image]

Comment: Did my answer address your problem @AbbasAli ?

Comment: @PradyumanDixit, I update my question with sreenshot.I want to get that user ID

Comment: I am talking about the same UID, without storing them in your database, you can't retrieve `uid` of any other user, except for the current user. For this you have to make a database structure resembling one in my answer, and act accordingly.

Comment: Hey @AbbasAli do mark the answer as correct, by clicking the V looking button next to the answer, it helps the future readers and I'd appreciate that. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would NOT recommend you to share UID of any user that openly because it can easily be misused if exposed in the app to any user.

This may be a threat to the security of your database.

That said, if you're sure that this won't be a problem in your case, then getting `uid` of any other user can only be done when you're storing the `uid` of all the authenticated users in your database.

Suppose you have a JSON structure like this:

```json
-FirebaseAndroidUniqueName
|
 -Users
  |
   -uid
   |
    -name
    -uid
    -otherThings
```

Then getting `uid` of any user can be done using a code like below:

```java
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
                    databaseReference.orderByChild("name").equalTo(userNameWhoseUidYouWant).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                               String uid = ds.child("uid").getValue(String.class);

                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
```